# How does git know my email?

Tags: git

`git log` correctly shows my full name and email address in the commit log. I don't remember ever *telling* git who I was. Have I just forgotten or does git get this information from somewhere else? (Linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's (likely) configured in the global git config.

You can verify it by running

```
git config --global --get user.email
```

Or more in general, you can list the entire global configuration with

```
git config --global -l
```

You probably configured it a long time about and forgot about it since then.

Comment: Yep - @spraff, you probably set this up when you first installed git for a different repository, but as the `--global` flag indicates, these configuration settings will be used for all repositories unless overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Check your email configuration by:

```
git config --list
```

In almost case, setup email address correctly is necessary:

```
git config user.email "foo@example.com"
```

Email is the first criteria for user identification.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have explicitly given git your address. The [`git commit-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html) describes how git approximates your attribution when all details are not known.

> While parent object ids are provided on the command line, author and committer information is taken from the following environment variables, if set:
>
> - GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
> - GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
> - GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
> - GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
> - GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
> - GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
>
> (NB: `<`, `>` and `\n` characters are stripped.)
>
> In case (some of) these environment variables are not set, the information is taken from the configuration items `user.name` and `user.email`, or, if not present, the environment variable `EMAIL`, or, if that is not set, system user name and the hostname used for outgoing mail (taken from `/etc/mailname` and falling back to the fully qualified hostname when that file does not exist).